# How to process too fibrous chicory?

Tags: vegetables, fiber

I recently bought a large jar of sautéed chicory (about 1.2 kilo), and upon eating the first serving I noticed that the long stems are extremely fibrous and difficult to chew, to the point that even a mouthful the size of teaspoon takes a good amount of chewing before being able to swallow it.

I have tried cutting the stems with knife and fork in the plate, with no appreciable result.

Is there any way I can process them to make the eating more manageable? The taste is excellent, but I would prefer to eat them without having to be fully and solely focused on just the chewing for fear of choking.